# How to simplify this java for each loop?

Tags: java, for-loop, csvjdbc

I'm trying to simplify the following code.

```
while(results.next())
    for(String column : colNames){
        if(EmptyUtil.isEmpty(results.getString(column))) {
            emptyCount++;
        }
    }
    
    if(emptyCount == colNames.size()){
        break;
    }
}
```

My main goal is to read a CSV file until an empty row and finish reading the file from there. And it's a necessity that I have to use this Csvjdbd driver ).

In the above code, `results` is a `CsvResultSet` (I've used Csvjdbc library to get this result set ). This CsvResultSet represents a single row in the CSV file inside the for loop. Basically I'm going through every row in the CSV file
b
`colNames` is the column headers list in the CSV. By using `results.toString(column)`, I can get the value in the particular cell in the row.

If all the cells are empty in the row, I should break from the while loop.

The above code works as expected. I just need to know how to simplify that more.

Comment: *If all the cells are empty in the row, I should break from the while loop.* - should not `emptyCount` be set back to zero for each row?

Comment: I haven't used this library, but since it is JDBC-styled, a couple of questions: (a) Is there is a primary key in a row? (b) if yes, can that be added to your `WHERE` clause, so that you don't have to make `null` checks and just go over the records fetched?

Comment: What solution did you choose?

Comment: @gaborsch all the below answers work. Thanks a lot for posting those answers. I chose a combination of your answer and Maurice Perry's answer. I liked your `allMatch` approach. It greatly reduces the processing time.

Comment: @ScaryWombat yes that's right. I have missed putting here I think. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
L: while(results.next()) {
    for(String column : colNames){
        if(!EmptyUtil.isEmpty(results.getString(column))) {
            continue L;
        }
    }
    // all the cells are empty in the row
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use Stream API to decide, and an external variable instead of `break`.

```
boolean wasEmptyRow = false;
while (!wasEmptyRow && results.next()) {
    wasEmptyRow = colNames
        .stream()
        .map(column -> results.getString(column))
        .allMatch(EmptyUtil::isEmpty);
    if (! wasEmptyRow) {
        // process
    }
}
```

You simply create a stream from the column names, replace all values with the current value from the `result`, then check if all of them are empty.
The `allMatch` is optimized, it will not check all columns if one failing case was found. This saves the `break` for you.

Comment: @gabrosch there's a catch on this approach though. results.getString method throws a CheckedException. Java's Stream API doesn't like CheckedExceptions much it seems :) I'm trying to find a proper way to handle this atm.

Comment: @AmilaFonseka true, checked exceptions are the enemy in the streaming world :) You can use the block approach: `.map(column -> { try { return results.getString(column); } catch (WhateverException e) { log.error(ex); }})`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is much simpler, but perhaps more readable:

```
while (results.next() && !allColumnsEmpty(results, colNames)) {
}
```

...

```
private boolean allColumsEmpty(ResultSet results, String...colNames) {
    for(String column : colNames){
        if(!EmptyUtil.isEmpty(results.getString(column))) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I ended up using a combination of this and gaborsch's solution. Thanks a lot for this!